# smtp port php configuration file

Tags: php, smtp

I have a php script set up to generate emails. Currently, they give the success message but don't actually send the email.

I just had a look in the php configuration settings file, and I noticed this:

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
SMTP = localhost
smtp_port = 25
```

Is this where I change the SMTP to the address I need the emails to be relayed through?

Any help would be appreciated, thanks :)

Comment: *Are* you on a Windows server?

Comment: @Pekka, Yes I am on windows server 2008

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're on Windows, PHP's mail function can use a SMTP server. (That is because Windows lacks Unix/Linux's centralized, standardized mailing functions.)

However, its possibilities are very limited: It supports neither authentication nor encryption - both things that most mail services require nowadays.

If you want to use an external SMTP server (like Google Mail's), an external mailing class like [Swiftmailer](http://www.swiftmailer.org) that can connect to SMTP servers using SSL/TLS and authentication.

Otherwise,a lightweight mail server like [Mercury](http://www.pmail.com/overviews/ovw_mercwin.htm) can accept local E-Mail and "re-send" it through a proper SMTP server.

Comment: Hi Pekka, Thanks for the reply. The thing is, I actually know the mail server I need to use. I have the address for it. I just wondered is this where I specify it? I tried it, and tested it but still no email.

Comment: @Tara see my updated answer. You're probably best off using Swiftmailer or PHPMailer

Comment: Thanks Pekka, all sorted now :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can set the server that's going to be used to send mails via SMTP there (as the comment states, this is WIN32 only!). I however suggest you have a look at [phpmailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/), which eases your work with sending mails in php. It supports custom SMTP settings aswell.